# Custom 'stemming' in Sphinx with Workforms?

Tags: sphinx, stemming

I've found the stem_en and lemmatizer to be either to limiting or inclusive for my needs. Can I make custom stemming with word forms? Either full workds

e.g. Procology > Procotologist

but idealy stems

ology > ologist

Answer (score 0):

No wordforms works on whole words, not 'ending'.

Would have to either use `regexp_filter`, or develop your own morphology processor (as C code)

Comment: Thanks, is the regexp_filter in the index as slow as regex is in general? I've compared regex vs sphinx and the differences are astounding, so does regexp_filter inside the index run as slolwy? I get it is just on the index and rotate but if I add a bunch of regexp's am I slowing down the indexing to the degree regular mysql regex would have?